# html request to server from different devices

Tags: php, mysql, html, request, device

I am a beginner site developper, first post here. I am posting here because i find this subject particulary difficult to google..

So I was wondering if you surf to a website from 2 different devices, (eg. android / PC ), if a different HTML page is returned..
because sometimes you get like a "simplified" page on the smaller devices.

If so, how can i do this server side? Any handy links/tutorials i can follow? I would work with PHP and MySql.

I am asking this, because I want to develop a site using QR codes, so the biggest number of visitors will be from phones!

Tanks,
Mathias

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [ask] and [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Responsive design - take a look at CSS media queries, and twitter bootstrap implementation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto detect mobile browser (via user-agent?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005153/auto-detect-mobile-browser-via-user-agent)

Comment: You didn't search well for this issue. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386046/how-do-i-determine-whether-its-a-mobile-device-with-php

Comment: As gordon says, most such apps decode $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this PHP class.
It detects mobile devices:

- http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/

There are also very simple solutions and tutorials like this one:

- [Detect mobile browser/user agent with PHP](http://www.dannyherran.com/2011/02/detect-mobile-browseruser-agent-with-php-ipad-iphone-blackberry-and-others/)

Searching [Google](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=php%20detect%20mobile%20device&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) or [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D%20detect%20mobile%20device) will give you loads of examples!