# Post to wall on Facebook: How to recognize Mobile / Desktop users?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

When my app posts an image on the wall on Facebook, there is also a link posted that leads to the facebook app.

If the post is seen on a desktop, I want the link to redirect them to the flash based facebook app.

If the post is seen on IOS, I want them instead to see the download link of the same app on the App Store.

Is that possible? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to change the Facebook link that would either redirect to one page or the other isn't a good practice (and that even wouldn't be possible). Just let the user click on the same link wherever he is using Facebook.

So, once the user on your web page, just catch the [user agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) which will give you information about his browser and device or computer. Depending on this, you'll know whether he is on a desktop or mobile phone. You'll then be able to redirect the user with the appropriate [URL redirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#HTTP_status_codes_3xx). I let you search on this side with some help:

- [How do I determine whether it's a mobile device with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386046/how-do-i-determine-whether-its-a-mobile-device-with-php)
- [Mobile_Detect](https://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/) is a lightweight PHP class for detecting mobile devices. It uses the user-agent string combined with specific HTTP headers to detect the mobile environment.
- For example: [what is your User Agent?](http://whatsmyuseragent.com/)
- [Detect Mobile Browsers | Open source mobile phone detection](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/)
- "[know if mobile browser](https://www.google.com/search?aq=f&oq=how%20to%20use%20user%20agents&%7Bgoogle:instantFieldTrialGroupParameter%7Dsourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=how%20to%20use%20user%20agents&hl=en#hl=en&safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&q=know%20if%20mobile%20browser&oq=know%20if%20mobile%20browser&gs_l=serp.3..0i30j0i22l2.3162.3294.1.3436.2.2.0.0.0.0.105.201.1j1.2.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.p2kcXwhzk00&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=3261b7d406fa296d&biw=1422&bih=701)" on Google